# What is the sizeof() Arduino's built in HIGH and LOW?

Tags: arduino-mega

This might be a stupid question to ask but I'm curious. I decided to test this myself and I got a value of 2 for both HIGH and LOW, why would it output 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Arduino AVR Boards, HIGH and LOW are currently macros:

https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/1.6.23/cores/arduino/Arduino.h#L40-L41

```
#define HIGH 0x1
#define LOW  0x0
```

This means that `sizeof(HIGH)` is equivalent to `sizeof(0x1)`. `0x1` is an [integer constant](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/constants/integerconstants/). The default type of integer constants is [int](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/int). On an 8 bit microcontroller like the ATmega2560 used by your Arduino Mega, an int is 16 bits.

That is why `sizeof(HIGH)` returns 2 (16 bits / 8 bits/byte = 2 bytes).